# Click while element isEnabled in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I have to click a right arrow button while is enabled on the page.

This is my code:

```
var sig = element(by.id('#right_button'));
sig.isEnabled().then(function (result) {
    while (result) {
        sig.click();
        return sig;
    }
}
```

It only clicks two times, and I need clicking while element is enabled. How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your element is on the DOM even before you start executing the loop as the loops get executed much more faster than we think. Probably waiting for an element to load before clicking on it should do the trick. Or instead using function calls, is the best approach to it. Here's how you can do it -

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var sig = element(by.id('#right_button'));

(function clickIt(){
  browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(sig), 2000).then(function(){
    sig.isEnabled().then(function (enabled) {
        if(enabled){
            sig.click().then(function(){
              clickIt.call();
            });
        }
    });
    });
})();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm going to test this way too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could there be a syntax error?
                }
                browser.sleep(3000);
            }();
        }

Comment: @winlinuz, yes my fault. I missed to close the bracket of `then()`. Updated the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers and your comments. I have tested the code and it only clicks one time. :( It doesn't follow clicking while the button is enabled.

Comment: @winlinuz, did you try it with the `browser.wait()` function too? You have to wait until the element is enabled. Updated the answer with the combined code. Also if your answer is solving the issue, please mark that as answer. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I tried with the browser.wait() function too. In fact, I tried with the new code proposed by you right now and It only clicks one time. I solved this with this code:

`var sig = element(by.id('#right_button'));
        reclick = function (sig) {
            sig.isEnabled().then(function (result) {

                if (result) {
                    sig.click();
                    return reclick(sig);
                }

            });
        };
        reclick(sig);`

Comment: @winlinuz yes, that should work too. Please mark that as answer that you have written below so that others find it helpful. Thanks :) Its clicking only once because i didn't set the value of `result = true` i guess.

Comment: Now It doesn't click with that change, nor the first.

Comment: With your last change in the code, it works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's a lot of sleeps considering you are already using `wait()`. I don't think isEnabled() does what you think it does. According to the docs, `Is the element currently enabled or not? This will generally return true for everything but disabled input elements.` I would use `isDisplayed()` and get rid of all the sleeps.

Comment: @JeffC, you are right, i was supposed to remove the sleeps but forgot to do so as they were required for the loop, which was the answer written before and then i changed it later. Also, user wants to click the element only if its enabled, so i guess `isEnabled` should do the trick, else the test should stop, thats what i intended to write. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Solved this way:

```
    var sig = element(by.id('#right_button'));
    reclick = function (sig) {
        sig.isEnabled().then(function (result) {

            while (result) {
                sig.click();
                return reclick(sig);
            }

        });
    };
    reclick(sig);
```